# Password protected screen in android

Tags: android

I have developed an app that stores all private data information hence I develop password protected screen.

When I open the app the password screen comes up properly but after logging in and if I am editing anything and then I press the home button I have an issue the app reopens to protected screen without the password.

How do I send it back to password screen onResume?

I need to figure out a way to get Home button pressed on Fragment and activity? Or is there a better option?

Can somebody help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: What about calling 'finish()' in 'onPause()' ? Or alternatively replace the actual Fragment with the password Fragment in 'onRestart()' ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call onPause and onDestroy, automatically log out of the server with that username + password. And then every time you log on make it check to see if you are connected/logged in to the server, if you are not (Which will always be the case) then switch to the login activity. Hope this helped. :)

Comment: What happens is when I press Home Button and then click recent button on my phone and then open the app. The protected screen comes up but I need to show password screen?

Comment: Change the activity to the Password screen on every onResume (A method that is called every time the activity is opened)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Android inbuild method 
onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState).
This is more easy and work well.

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)